# micro ampere measurements

Tags: current-measurement, measurement, low-power

This question is very basic but I could not find it among previous questions so here it goes:
I am trying to measure the current of a very low power device with very short intervals of activity. I know I should use a shunt resistor and OPAMP but:

1) I am not sure about the correct configurations and setup of these wrt device

2) I am not sure about the range of the resistor and the specifications of the OPAMP that should be used in this matter.

The range of the currents to be measured are starting from 10 microamperes to a few mili amperes

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/220844/how-to-measure-supply-currents-ranging-from-1μa-to-10ma?rq=1 make your question more specific by sharing your specific circuit. What components you have and your progress till now. It is possible then to receive good helpful response from others.

Comment: This is not a "very basic" question. Not that uA is a super-small value these days, but measuring anything small/smallish or large/largish tends to require some work. Commentary aside, you need to determine a few more things: bandwidth, common mode voltage, allowable error, allowable insertion loss; just to name a few off the top of my head. Maybe read this: http://www.mccdaq.com/support/Data-Acquisition-Handbook.aspx?oid=1820